# Can't get randomized JSON object attributes using Wikipedia API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to code a small Wikipedia client that can, among other things, grab a snippet from a random article through the Wikipedia API. I want to accomplish this by using jQuery to pull a random article from this API call: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exchars=500&format=jsonfm

The problem is that I don't know what to call in order to get the title and extract in the returned JSON object. If I call my object `result` then I basically need to access `result.query.pages.(thepageid).title` and `result.query.pages.(thepageid).extract` but since the pageid is random, I don't know what to write instead of `(thepageid)` - I've tried result.query.pages[0], but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas of how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and extract `title` and `extract` like this:

```js
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exchars=500&format=json&callback=?', function(response) {
    var pages = response.query.pages,
        id = Object.keys(pages)[0],
        randomPage = pages[id];

    console.log(randomPage.title);
    console.log(randomPage.extract);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you - that seems to have done the trick :D. Object.keys(pages)[0] was exactly what I had been searching for

Answer (score 0):

if available, you might want to use `Object.values` on `result.query.pages`. That would give you a list of objects containing the `extract` key.

```
// first element 
var page = Object.values(result.query.pages)[0];
console.log(page.title);
```

Other solution, of there are more ID to value pairs, you could iterate over

```
for (let id in result.query.pages) {
    console.log('ID:' + id);
    console.log('VALUE:' + result.query.pages[id]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`formatversion=2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exchars=500&format=jsonfm&formatversion=2):

```js
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exchars=500&format=json&formatversion=2&callback=?', function(response) {
    console.log(response.query.pages[0].extract);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have checked your code and do not work because `response.query.pages` is an object and not an array